# c# running command line with two arguments

Tags: c#, command-line

so I'm currently working on a BlueJ like clone for c#. Now I want to compile all the .cs files in the working folder on click for which I use: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /define:DEBUG /optimize /out:Program.exe *.cs` which I took from the msdn page. For that to work though I need to be in the right directionary so I use the following: `cd /d  + dir` where dir is the directionary of the files. Now when I try to run that from c# like this:

```
cmd = @"cd /d "+ dir + @" && C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /define:DEBUG /optimize /out:Program.exe *.cs";
        file = "cmd";
        var proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(file, cmd);
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.ErrorDataReceived += proc_DataReceived;
        proc.OutputDataReceived += proc_DataReceived;

        proc.Start();

        proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

nothing happenes. But when I try to run the command in the cmd window it works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the command with

```
cmd.exe /c
```

cmd.exe expects parameter "/c" if you want to pass over an execution command.

So:

```
cmd = @"/c cd /d "+ dir + @" && C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /define:DEBUG /optimize /out:Program.exe *.cs";
```

should work

Comment: Thanks for the anwser but now even less happenes since this doesn't even work when using the console. It now tells me that it couldn't find the command /c couldnt be found